# Button and Textfield resizing and aligning

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

I built a calculator. I was not able to align the buttons, and the textfield of the calculator in the form that I desire.

I used **GridPane** due to the fact that I thought it would be easier to control the buttons. I read Oracle's documents online and I still can't figure this out.

How do you resize/align buttons and textfields in JavaFX?

I used **HBox** for the textfield, because it is only one figure and it is the easiest way to control it.

The calculator itself works, the problem is the resizing and aligning of the buttons and textfield.

Here's a picture of my calculator:

[image]

Here are pieces of my code that control the GridPane:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setPadding(new Insets(10 ,10 ,10 ,10));
grid.setVgap(4);
grid.setHgap(4);
HBox topMenu = new HBox(); // Display -- top of the window

grid.getChildren().addAll(button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, plusButton, subButton, multiButton, divButton, eqButton, clearButton,npButton,decButton,percentButton);
topMenu.getChildren().add(display);

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setTop(topMenu);
borderPane.setCenter(grid);

Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
window.setScene(scene);
window.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569575/how-to-automatically-resize-buttons-on-borderpane-as-the-window-is-resized?rq=1

Comment: @IvanPronin The guy in the case that you suggested ended up using HBox, and I still want to use GridPane. The things he wanted to do were also different as he wanted to keep a unified distance between the button when he expended the window, and I to align the button better.

Comment: You haven't done anything to specify where in the grid pane any of the controls are supposed to be positioned. There are many different ways to do this, e.g. using `grid.add(button0, 0, 1);` or `GridPane.setColumnIndex(button0, 0); GridPane.setRowIndex(button0, 1);`. Or you can just use `grid.addRow(...)` etc. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) and try one of the approaches there.

Comment: If you used an `HBox` for the `TextField`. First, add a `StackPane`. Then add the `TextField` to the `StackPane`.

Comment: Other methods listed in the documentation may be useful too, e.g. [`GridPane.setFillWidth(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setFillWidth-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean-), or using column constraints with appropriate properties set.

Comment: Go look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103809/how-can-i-get-the-text-from-textfield-javafx/45104516#45104516). Look for the pure code solution, not the `FXML` solution.